# Is it needed to upgrade perl to new stable version in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, perl

as above! thanks!
  Can you suggest a book for this question?

Comment: "As above" doesn't go nearly far enough to explain what you're asking. What are you talking about? What is your problem? Please edit your question to give a little context so that people can understand what you need in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The latest stable version for 12.04 Precise is 5.14.2 (perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2)) is available from the repositories. If you want the latest and greatest (5.18.0), you will need to download and compile it from source.

You can download it [here](http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.18.0.tar.gz).

I would recommend using [App::perlbrew](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GUGOD/App-perlbrew-0.64/README) to assist you in building this local to your $HOME directory.

Answer (score 1):

In general? No, people were productive using much older version of Perl in years past.

For specific usages? Perhaps, depending on what you want to do. Each new version of *any* package usually contains several small changes that affect only a few use cases, with occasional larger changes (all of which are documented in something called a "change log"). If you need a specific feature that was only added recently, then yes, upgrading would make sense.